# MySQL and Raspberry Pi Error

Tags: php, mysql, raspberry-pi

When I try to start mysql via putty:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

It gives me this error:

> Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service failed to load: No such file or directory...

Also upon typing:

```
mysql -rroot -p
```

It gives me:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Is mysql-server installed and running on the Raspberry?

Comment: Yes well no, I am trying to get it to work.